# Angular JSON Schema pattern for 12 digit number not working

Tags: angular, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am using Angular JSON Schema in my project, i want to validate a text box using pattern. I cannot use maxLength property.

```
"[\\d+]{12}
```

JSON Schema internally removes the extra \

The problem is that it is not restricting the input to 12 digits, it will be invalid till i type 12 digits once it becomes valid if i add few more digits to make it 13,14 or even bigger digit number it still remains valid

Here is a link of Angular JSON Schema playground

https://angular2-json-schema-form.firebaseapp.com/?set=asf&example=asf-simple&framework=bootstrap-3&language=en

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use :

```
pattern="[0-9]{0,12}" // for 0 or to 12 number

pattern="[0-9]{12}" // for exact 12 digit number validation
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pattern-validation)**

For Angular JSON Schema playground you should use `^` and `$`:

```
pattern="^[0-9]{0,12}$" // for 0 or to 12 number

pattern="^[0-9]{12}$" // for exact 12 digit number validation
```

Comment: Yours is a valid Regex as was mine, but the problem is that it does not work in Angular JSON Schema. You can try in the link given

Comment: @curiosa , I have tried mine and it's working completely fine with both  `"pattern": "[0-9]{0,12}",` and `"pattern": "[0-9]{12}",`

Comment: The demo which you have given is of plain angularjs, the issue is in angular-json-schema. It is a form builder and validator library  https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form

Comment: @curiosa , I have tested on your given url for `JSON Schema playground` , I have changed the pattern over there and test the code , and it is working.

Comment: You can add `"pattern": "[0-9]{0,12}",` to `schema.properties.name` and test

Comment: Doesn't work, even if you type more than 12 numbers, form remains valid